# How to convert a c program to 8051 microcontroller assembly code

Tags: c, 8051

I looked through several sites ,but, I am not able to find a suitable answer. It seems really hard to convert my c programme to assembly code...

Comment: It has nothing to do with CSS at least...

Comment: Try to find and use some [cross-compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler), or else do the conversion manually (on paper or screen). But your question is completely **off-topic** here. For your next question on SO,  please provide an [MCVE]

Comment: What's the actual purpose? I mean, you can generate assembly with `-S`, but it's not the same assembly a human would write.

Comment: @DaveNewton yeah,I have a c program but I am not able to convert the programme to microcontroller assembly code...

Comment: Why not?   What error did you get?

Comment: @MartinJames I don't know.

Comment: #include<reg51.h>
#define lcd P1

sbit rs=P3^6;
sbit e=P3^7;
sbit relay=P0^0;
sbit s1=P2^0;
sbit s2=P2^1;

void delay (int);
void cmd (char);
void display (char);
void init (void);
void string (char *);
void view (int);

int count=0;
int no[10]={ 48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57 };

void delay (int d)
{ 
   unsigned char i=0;
   for(;d>0;d--)
   {  
      for(i=250;i>0;i--);  
      for(i=248;i>0;i--); 
   }
}

void cmd (char c)
{ 
   lcd=c; 
   rs=0; 
   e=1; 
   delay(5); 
   e=0;
}

void display (char c)
{ 
   lcd=c; 
   rs=1; 
   e=1; 
   delay(5); 
   e=0;
}

void string (char *p)
{ 
   whil

Comment: @Christie: never comment your own question. But **edit your question** instead. BTW, the accepted answer is wrong and not helpful to you (because you practically need a cross-compiler, not an ordinary straight one).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/978189/841108 is a near duplicate (but also off-topic)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch sorry for commenting on my on post....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thankyou

Answer (score -2, accepted):

With GCC you can generate assembly code with the `-S` flag.

Example:

`gcc -S hw.c`

I have try it in some small program but don't know hot that will do with large programs.

Comment: But OP needs 8051 assembler, not x86 one. So he needs a *cross-compiler* (which most `gcc` are not); and it is preferable to pass `-fverbose-asm` (and probably also `-O`) with `-S`

Comment: When I answered theses information were not mentioned. The question has been edited.

Comment: gcc can most definitely cross-compile, it has numerous back-ends.

Comment: But a cross-compiler is generally not called `gcc` but something else like `avr-gcc`. You'll pass some extra options at GCC's `configure` time. All the `gcc` programs I heard about are straight GCC compilers (not cross-compilers)

Comment: GCC doesn't do 8051. If you want free I suppose your only option is SDCC, if you want to pay there's Keil, IAR and others.

Answer (score 1):

if you use keil uvision ,than
1. goto Debug >> click "start/stop Debug Session" it'll start simulator if ide 2. 
2. view >> click Disassembly Window and you can see the assembly.

if not then go to below link and download it DIS8051 Cross-Disassembler V2.1 (you need hex file to convert your program to assembly of 8051)
http://bit.kuas.edu.tw/~8051/